# Array List size return zero size outside the if condition?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a array list with three element stored in it.In an if condition i have removed one element ,it removing fine but when i check the size of the array list outside the if condition it return zero value.Please anyone help me.i have followed these steps...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv_moves = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_moves);
    tv_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
    ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arl.add(1);
    arl.add(2);
    arl.add(3);
    ArrayList<Integer>remain=new ArrayList<>();
    mGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < NBR_ITEMS; i++) {
        final View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, mGrid, false);
        final TextView text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        if (i == 4) {
            itemView.setEnabled(false);
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
            int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(arl.size());
            Integer item1 = arl.get(index);
            text.setText(item1.toString());
            array[4] = item1.toString();
            arl.remove(index);
            System.out.println("array element list==="+arl);
            remain.add(0,arl.get(0));
            remain.add(1,arl.get(1));
            checkSubmit();
            text.setPadding(60, 30, 10, 10);

        }
        if (i == 3) {
            System.out.println("size of array list at 3=="+arl.size());//here i got the size 3 but i think it should be 2


           itemView.setEnabled(false);
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
            int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(arl.size());
            Integer item2 = arl.get(index);
            text.setText(item2.toString());

            array[3] = item2.toString();
            checkSubmit();
            text.setPadding(60, 30, 10, 10);
        }
```

Comment: any global instance with this "arl" name?

Comment: No, i have just created an Array List inside onCreate as you can see in my code.There is nothing in Globally.At i==4 when i remove the element it gives fine but when i check the size at i==3 it gives again  size of array 3.It should be 2 because i have remove one element previously.

Comment: Why are you deleting index element from arl ?

Comment: Actually i need to set value to grid view and no two value at the adjacent position that's why.

Comment: please edit your source, and add also where you check list size and give zero value.

Comment: when i add the value to other array List  and check the size of array at i==3 it gives zero value and when i check the size of array i.e  arl arry it gives size 3 .

Comment: Because you add items in (i==4) step. It comes after (i==3). That's why it gives you zero value.

Comment: @JavadKhan  yah thankyou ,its working fine now.I have notice it after posting the question.Thank you so much.

Comment: you are welcome!